# Missing placeholder value crash occurs during global variable initialization?

Tags: tensorflow, placeholder

On tensorflow 1.4. I'm getting the `you need a value for placeholder tensor...` error. Thing is I *am* feeding this tensor like

```
            feats = np.reshape(feats, (-1, var1, feat_dim, 1))
            _, outlogits = sess.run([train_step, logits], feed_dict={inp_layer: feats,
                                                                     targs: targets,
                                                                     eta: 1e-4})
```

(normally I'd want to reshape inside of the graph but for debugging purposes I've taken that out)

placeholder:

```
inp_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, var1, feat_dim, 1])
```

The error says: `You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [?,66,200,1]`

And this error occurs when I run `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`, so it hasn't even gotten to the part where it should start thinking about placeholders and yet it's complaining about them?!

I think it might have to do with the fact that one of my layer sizes is dependent on a placeholder.. (I have `validate_shape=False` for the weights though). Will add more code.

edit: example code that fails, point out where I think the problem is coming from (remember code fails on global variable init):

!edit2: YUP the problem is that line. The question then becomes how can I have a graph where the dimensions of one the weights (and therefore the outputs) is dynamic.

```
train_feats = '..'
train_json = '..'
feat_dim = 200
var1 = 20
batch_size = 64

inp_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, var1, feat_dim, 1])
targs = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None])
eta = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

chunk_size = 3
w1 = init_weight([chunk_size, feat_dim, 1, 32])
b1 = tf.zeros([32])
a1 = conv_layer(inp_layer, w1, b1, stride=3, padding='VALID')

chunk_size = tf.shape(a1)[1]  <==== # ! IS THE PROBLEM !
w5 = init_weight([chunk_size, 1, 32, 12])
b5 = tf.zeros([12])
a5 = conv_layer(a1, w5, b5, stride=1, padding='VALID', act=False)
logits_ = tf.reshape(a5, [-1, 12])

softmax = tf.nn.softmax(logits_)
cross_ent = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=targs,
                                                                            logits=logits_))

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(eta).minimize(cross_ent)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for feats, targets in batch_gen(train_feats, train_json, var1, feat_dim):
        feats = np.reshape(feats, (var1, var1, feat_dim, 1))
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={inp_layer: bla,
                                        targs: targets,
                                        eta: 1e-4})

def init_weight(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.01), validate_shape=False)


def conv_layer(x, w, b, stride, padding, act=True):
    # striding over the features
    if act:
        return tf.nn.elu(tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, [1, stride, 1, 1], padding) + b)
    else:
        return tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, [1, stride, 1, 1], padding) + b
```

Comment: It would help to see more of your code. At least enough code so that we can replicate the error.

Comment: I've added some more code. I'll try and provide something reproducable but that will take more time.

Comment: I think you're right about the line of code causing the error. In the second assignment of `chunk_size`, shouldn't that always equal `feat_dim`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
chunk_size = tf.shape(a1)[1]
```

`tf.shape` extracts the runtime shape of `a1`, not the static shape known at graph definition time. Since `a1` is the result of the convolution between `inp_layer` and `w1`, when you reference `a1` you need also to resolve `inp_layer`. Because `inp_layer` is a placeholder, your error follows.

Since you're interested in the second dimension of `a1` that is know at graph definition time, you can just use:

```
chunk_size = a1.shape[1].value
```

to extract the correct dimension value.

Comment: `Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor.`

Comment: post the output of `print(a1.shape)` and `print(a1.shape[1].value)` please

Comment: Sorry that was a different error. Real one is because none is returned `Expected binary or unicode string, got None`. Not surprising since `print(a1.shape) == (?, ?, ?, 32)` and `print(a1.shape[1].value) == None`

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that I'm initializing the weights with `None` shape. So `print(w1.shape) == <unknown>`, which is probably leading to all the `?` for a1

Comment: There's something wrong with what are you doing. Your weights must have a well-defined shape (e.i. `[3,3,3,32]`)

Comment: Solved it! The code was different earlier and for that I had set `validate_shape=False` for the weights (see bottom of code). This lead to the `unknown` weight values. Thank your for leading me in the right direction. :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help you!